# fireEvent.change is not working for the input element inside child component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I have a main component

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import InputBox from "@someOther/forms/lib/components/input-box";

export const mainComponent = ():JSX.Element => {

  const [value, setValue] = useState({number:{value:""}});

  const handleUpdate = (fieldValue, val) => {
    setValue({number: {value: val}})
  }

  const {number} = value;

  return(
    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
    <div>
      <InputBox
        type="text"
        labelTedxt=""
        id="num"
        value={number.value}
        onUpdate={(value:string) => handleUpdate("number", value)}
      />
    </div>
  )
}

export default mainComponent;
```

I am trying to change the value of the inputBox using fireEvent.change in my test which is a component and imported from somewhere else.

OR

If i could pass some value to the InputBox when i do render() in my test.

OR if i could call handleUpdate in my test.

Test file

```
import {mainComponent} from "./mainComponent";
import {screen, render, fireEvent} from "@testing-library/react";
import InputBox from "@someOther/forms/lib/components/input-box";

describe("Verify if input box accepts value", () => {
  const {container} = render(<mainComponent/>);

  it("should change input element value", () => {
    const inputEl = screen.getAllByRole("textbox")[0];
    fireEvent.change(inputEl, {target: {value: "fakeValue214353"}});
    const inputElAfterValueChange = screen.getAllByRole("textbox")[0];
    expect(inputElAfterValueChange.getAttribute("value")).to.equal(fakeValue214353);
  });
});
```

when i run the test it fails. i tried to see what value the input element is loading using sreen.debug() and it shows <input value="" ..../>

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the `InputBox` implementation

Comment: @LinDu sorry i dont think it has anything to do with the InputBox, it is just a component which is imported from some other folder. And that is where the issue is. If you have input field in your parent component it is working fine. Its just not working when that input field is coming in a child component and we want to access it.

Comment: You can replace the `InputBox` with the `input` element and try it. It works fine. Besides, you should post the test result so we can know why the test failed.